# Sencha Touch Panel rendering issue

Tags: sencha-touch

We are developing a tablet oriented application in Sencha Touch with multiple List objects side by side surrounding each one by a panel, all of this inside a big panel in our Viewport view (consider we are follow MVC strategies recommended by Sencha Staff).

Our problem is we are trying to trigger an event or method after each surrounding panel is created (we called it EVENT_NAME_TO_TRIGGER for reference) to update its child list/contents, this code snippet maybe is helpful:

```
// i iterate from 0 to n to create multiples panels
var i = new Ext.Panel({
    dockedItems :  {
        cls: 'toolbar',
        xtype : 'toolbar',
        title : rec.data.title                                
    },
    width: 250,

    style: "margin-right:5px;" +
           "margin-top:10px;" +
           "margin-left:5px;" +
           "background-color:#FFFFFF;",
           "EVENT_NAME_TO_TRIGGER": function(){
               Ext.apply(this, {
                   items: aux
           });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's a Panel rendering issue you can solve this issue by adding `.doLayout()` function